# How to remove td in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I remove a `td` cell in a table with MVC4?

Could I use JQuery or JavaScript? And if so, how?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblParticipantList">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Adress</th>
            <th>Redeem Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-id="columnId" id="customerPartial_94">
            <td data-field="NAME">Attn Donna</td>
            <td data-field="ADDRESS">3046 Lavon Drive Newyork America 7504</td>
            <td data-field="SECURITY_REDEMPTION_CD"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="columnId" id="customerPartial_95">
            <td data-field="NAME">F 1 La 1</td>
            <td data-field="ADDRESS">Asd 1 s 1 Ci 1 s</td>
            <td data-field="SECURITY_REDEMPTION_CD"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If possible, do this server side with ASP.net, unless the column is going to be displayed later.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To remove TD item, you should know exactly td what you want to remove.

1. Remove All TD item

   ```
   $('#tblParticipantList > tr > td').remove();
   ```
2. Remove TD at specified Row

   ```
   $('#tblParticipantList > tr').eq(rowNum).children('td').remove();
   ```
3. Remove TD at specified Row and Column

   ```
   $('#tblParticipantList > tr').eq(rowNum).children('td').eq(colNum).remove();
   ```

Comment: @NullPoiиteя that's right... And thank for your editing

Answer (score 4):

Remove child `td` of the position you want using `eq()`. Use proper id and class in the selector for expected result.

```
$('.table-striped tr').each(function(){
    $(this).children('td').eq(3).remove();
});
```